# 400 (Bad Request) when calling ajax using POST method

Tags: ajax, jquery, post

I become crazy with calling ajax... Ialways get 400 or sometimes 403 error

POST http://www.my.domain/api/rest/member/2/service 400
      (Bad Request)

My javascript is

```
            var Data = [];
            $('#troc > ul > li:not(.addArea)').each(function(){
                    var title = unescape(encodeURIComponent($(this).find('.title').text()));
                    var stock = parseInt($(this).find('.command').text());
                    var img = $(this).find('.left .thumb').attr('src');
                    var content = unescape(encodeURIComponent($(this).find('.description').text()));
                    Data.push({'title':title,'stock':stock,'img':img,'content':content});
            });

            console.log(JSON.stringify(Data));

            $.ajax({
                url: '../api/rest/member/2/service',
                type: 'POST',
                data: JSON.stringify(Data),
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                dataType: 'json',
                processData: false,
                cache: false
            })
            .done(function(data){
                if (!data.erreur) $.comment.msg({ content:data.message,type:'success' });
                else $.troc.msg({ content:data.message,type:'error' });
                $('form[name=postComment] input[type!="submit"][type!="hidden"]').val('');
                $('form[name=postComment] textarea').val('');
            })
            .fail(function(){
                $.troc.msg({ content:'Erreur inconnue',type:'error' });
            });
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/api/rest/member/2/service',
```

Don't include `..` in the url, instead use a relative url. My assumption is that `..` is causing problems for you.

Comment: I include .. instead of http://www.my.domain just for the question...
I just resolved the problem, stupdid error in the rest service, but thanks !